# Castle Logging Facility and log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator

Tags: log4net, castle-windsor, log4net-configuration

Does the Castle Logging Facility support anything in the way of what log4Net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch() does? I'd like to use the Windsor logging facility but I'd really like to be able to change the logging config at runtime as well. Can anyone point me in the direction of how I'd accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [file](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core/blob/master/src/Castle.Services.Logging.log4netIntegration/Log4netFactory.cs) in the Castle source repository, the Castle log4net implementation does (or can) do a ConfigureAndWatch.  I haven't used Castle, so I can't comment on exactly how to take advantage of this.  My first guess is that it should "just work".  If you are using Castle and you can configure its logging to use log4net, you might already be getting ConfigureAndWatch.  It is possible that ConfigureAndWatch only works if you configure log4net in its own config file (as opposed to the app.config or web.config).  It should not be too difficult to test (if you are already using Castle) to see if ConfigureAndWatch works as expected.

If you are not using Castle already, you might want to wait for someone more familiar with Castle and Castle logging to post an answer.

Here are another SO post about Castle logging that you might find helpful:

This one shows log4net configuration in the app.config/web.config (the accepted answer is from February 2010.  I don't know if there is more recent information available or not):

[Logging with Castle.Facilities.Logging and log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297282/logging-with-castle-facilities-logging-and-log4net)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely right. I just opened the Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration DLL with reflector and confirmed what you pointed out. The default factory configures and watches config files - including the app.config file. I've just proven it by editing my log4net config at runtime :) Thanks very much!