# How do I pass log4net config file thru code to Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.UseLog4Net?

Tags: castle-windsor, log4net, castle, log4net-configuration

I am using the following code from castle windsor documentation.
I can't figure out how to pass in my configFile on my bootstrapper container installer that installs this installer.

```
 public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net("NameOfConfigFile"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have been able to do this is by newing up my installer and passing in the NameOfConfigFile and in the constructor of my installer setting a private instance field to this value.

```
_bootStrapContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new LoggerInstaller(configPath));
```

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe it will use a logging.config on the root of the project. Do you still need to use something more customized than that?

Comment: UseLog4Net method has an overload that accepts string  configFile name to use, I am asking how to pass it in? because diff clients consuming my library will have diff log4net config files.

Comment: @rarouš What do you mean it is a deployment issue? Please clarify.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to pass the name/path of the Log4Net config file to the Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.UseLog4Net during container install.  Merlyn Morgan-Graham answer here is close to what I am asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297282/logging-with-castle-facilities-logging-and-log4net

Comment: You don't have to change config file names in app, you just deploy correct config into file with specified name.

Comment: @rarouš I don't think you understand what I am asking. I am asking how to dynamically pass in the log4net config file to UseLog4Net when my installers are installed.